# How to get the azure Cloud Service(Classic) Certificate Details with Expired Date, Certificate Name, Thumbprint

Tags: azure, powershell, az

I have got the all cloud Service (Classic) Certificate details with expired date, certificate name and his thumbprint

I expect this type of Output

---

Cloud Service Name
Cloud Service Certificate Name
Cloud Service Expired Date
Cloud Service Thumbprint

Note:- We do not used the AzureRm command

Comment: What are you asking for ? Have you tried something ? Could you give more details on what you need ? I am guessing you can get this information from the portal ? What are you trying to achive ? Running a script that check if a cert is about to expire or something like that ? Could you explain a little bit more your use case, it will be helpful :-)

Comment: Yes i know i can easily get this information from Portal but my requirement is using Azure Cli command. First, i got the all certificate information in script then after i will post this information in slack through web hook. I have tried to some azure cli command but i am not find out to any information.

Comment: What have you tried, are you able to show up any steps you've already taken or actions taken? Perhaps code you've already started to write?

Comment: it hould be possible using az cli v1 but not v2 as v2 only support ARM and not classic resources. Have you checked az cli v1 ?

Comment: Matthew I have not  taken any steps or writing a code. I am not getting any information.

Comment: So I've cheked you can do it using azure cli v1: https://github.com/azure/azure-xplat-cli. once installed set mode to classic `azure config mode asm` then if you run `azure service cert list --serviceName myServiceName` it should give you information about cert installed on the cloud service

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to simple call the rest api for getting Certificate. Here is the api which would give you certificate details which is under one particular resource group.(Example includes Azure web services)

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates?api-version=2016-03-01
```

Sample request

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/34adfa4f-cedf-4dc0-ba29-b6d1a69ab345/resourceGroups/testrg123/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates?api-version=2016-03-01
```

and here is the sample response.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/34adfa4f-cedf-4dc0-ba29-b6d1a69ab345/resourceGroups/testrg123/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/testc6282",
      "name": "testc6282",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
      "location": "East US",
      "properties": {
        "friendlyName": "",
        "subjectName": "ServerCert",
        "hostNames": [
          "ServerCert"
        ],
        "issuer": "CACert",
        "issueDate": "2015-11-12T23:40:25+00:00",
        "expirationDate": "2039-12-31T23:59:59+00:00",
        "thumbprint": "FE703D7411A44163B6D32B3AD9B03E175886EBFE",
        "password": "SWsSsd__233$Sdsds#%Sd!"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/34adfa4f-cedf-4dc0-ba29-b6d1a69ab345/resourceGroups/testrg123/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/testc4912",
      "name": "testc4912",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
      "location": "West US",
      "properties": {
        "friendlyName": "",
        "subjectName": "ServerCert2",
        "hostNames": [
          "ServerCert2"
        ],
        "issuer": "CACert",
        "issueDate": "2015-12-12T23:40:25+00:00",
        "expirationDate": "2040-12-31T23:59:59+00:00",
        "thumbprint": "FE703D7411A44163B6D32B3AD9B0490D5886EBFE",
        "password": "SWsSsd__233$Sdsds#%Sd!"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can find the more details here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/listbyresourcegroup

Hope it helps.